# how to close the file upload window after the file is being uploaded in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I can not close the finder window that has taken the desired file that I wanted to upload with selenium webdriver.

Here is my code:

```
WebElement changeFle=driver.findElement(By.id("tradeDocFile"));

changeFle.click();

changeFle.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\ranjan\\Downloads\\Selenium Program_Xpath_CssSelectors.pdf");

driver.findElement(By.id("btnSaveTradeDocument")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

After it gets executed file is being uploaded but file upload "Open" window is not being closed.

Comment: I would first suggest that your remove your `changeFle.click();` line. Just find the element, send the path and the enter key. This should mean that the explorer window shouldn't be opened but the file will still be uploaded with the submit line.

Answer (score 0):

WebElement changeFle=driver.findElement(By.id("tradeDocFile"));

// no need to click on upload button
 changeFle.click();

changeFle.sendKeys("C:\Users\ranjan\Downloads\Selenium Program_Xpath_CssSelectors.pdf");

driver.findElement(By.id("btnSaveTradeDocument")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a direct way to close it, because this window is kind of system File manager window that is opened by OS (Windows or MacOS, other). So the only way I found to do it is:

- press the open file button
- send file to needed input
- close driver using `driver.close()`

I understand, that it is not the super direct solution that is desired, but I built my flow another way, e.g:

- downloaded the needed CSV file
- updated the file
- uploaded file back
- closed driver.
- opened a driver again
- download the second file
- updated the second file
- closed a driver
  ...

Answer (score -1):

1) If you want to upload by sending the file path then no need to click on Browse(Or whatever the name of the button)

2) If you want to upload using the dialog box then use `Auto IT` or `Sikuli`

Thanks